# How is this for loop terminated?

Tags: c++, for-loop, conditional-statements

Found as a user submission on leetcode for the problem `Plus One`.

```
vector<int> plusOne(vector<int>& digits) {
  for (int i=digits.size(); i--; digits[i] = 0)
      if (digits[i]++ < 9)
          return digits;
  digits[0]++;
  digits.push_back(0);
  return digits;
}
```

Normally there's something in the conditional like `i >= 0;` How is this for loop terminating and not accesing some -i element?

Comment: I should mention I really like the look and flow of the code, might even use something similar in a coding interview. I obviously would need to be able to speak on it though if I plan on using it!

Comment: Obviously. How and why?

Comment: 0 is the same as false

Comment: So anytime I'm using a for loop to decrement i, putting `i > =0` is just sugar and not necessary?

Comment: ***is just sugar and not necessary?*** For readability I would always use i >= 0

Comment: @Podo Unless `i` is negative.

Comment: @drescherjm or [`i --> 0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c)

Comment: for (size_t i=digits.size(); --i==0; digits[i] = 0) would be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

A for loop terminates when the second expression is `false` or when [contextually converted to a bool value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) produces `false`. In C++, 0 is contextually converted to false; all other integers convert to true in a bool context. (Thanks to M.M.for the link.)

So at the beginning of each loop the expression `i--` is evaluated. It's just an expression, so it will produce a result. If the result it produces is zero, the loop will end. If you haven't seen this expression before, here is how it works:

- It both decrements i and returns the original value of i before it was decremented. So if `i` were 5, evaluating `i--` will have the "result" 5, but as a side effect, `i` will be 4 after the evaluation.

The big picture: `i` is decremented by 1 each time, so assuming it starts off positive, it will get down to 0, at which time evaluating `i--` will produce 0.

Comment: So a conditional must be included if there is some increment (like `i < 10`; i++`) but when you decrement the conditional is automatically greater than 0?

Comment: Any a value other than 0 is true

Comment: No conditional is needed, interestingly enough. `i--` always returns a value. If `i` were 5, say, then evaluating `i--` will produce the value 5, and _as a side effect_ cause `i` to be 4.

Comment: Nice link, I will add that.

Comment: Didn't know that was U.B., thanks! Will remove that and look into it, cool.

Comment: @M.M. if I am reading [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) correctly, then starting with C++ 11 you _do_ get guarantees that the value computation of a postfix increment is sequenced before its side-effect. Prior to C++ 11 we had the "sequence points" (remember those?) in which case there may be U.B.